# How do you find a certain method in ALL java classes in an application?

Tags: java

At runtime, I want to find ALL possible classes in an application that have a certain load method. If so then I would run it. The only problem is... Well I can't figure out how to check all the classes for that method.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to search source code or JARs?

Comment: Source code. I want to know how to look in ALL classes for a load method.

Comment: The OP means via reflection at runtime (it's implied in a comment on one of the answers below).

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect what I think the OP (Sonofmetal) is really asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the method is on a particular class or interface, you can right-click on the method name, select References and then either Project or Workspace and it will show all the uses of that method in the project or workspace. This assumes that all of the source for the project in question is loaded into Eclipse.

Comment: Well no I meant how could I look in ALL possible classes to find a specific load method.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you want to do this programmatically at runtime (my assumption) or just a text search (what the other answers assume). If the classes are already loaded you can use `Instrumentation.getAllLoadedClasses()` to get a list of all classes, then iterate through each of those, using `Class.getDeclaredMethod()` to find the method you are looking for, and you can invoke it that way.

If the classes have not been loaded you will have to explicitly load them first (e.g. with `Class.forName()` if you know their names, or by scanning your source tree for `.class` files to load.)

Comment: Ok...That helps more, but how would I invoke? I'm not good on invoking. Thanks for the help though! :)

Comment: By reading the documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html and checking out a reflection tutorial, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html :)